# What is the main solution for getting foreign key objects?

Tags: java, object, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables:

Persons: (Id, Name)

Addresses: (Id, Address, PersonID)

It means each person has some addresses.
I have object related to each table and a property for each foreign key object. In this example:

```
Class Persons
{
    int     id;
    string  name;
}

Class Addresses
{
    int     id;
    string  address;
    Persons person;
}
```

When I want to get all of my persons with their addresses I use left join. I create a collection of Address class and reach to each Person using "person" property.

But in some cases there are some persons that don't have any addresses. How can I access to that persons in my objects using this method. What is the best method for this situation?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use JPA. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html

Comment: I am using this method on Android

Comment: The name of the class should be "Person", not "Persons" :)

Comment: Why not model it like - a "Person"(may or may not) HAS A "Address"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found this solution:

```
Class Persons
{
    int     id;
    string  name;
    AddressesCollection addresses;
}

Class Addresses
{
    int     id;
    string  address;
    Persons person;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a collection of Persons that contains all the Persons that don't have address.
You also can create a dummy address and associate this to all the Persons that don't have it.

Comment: this is not a structural solution. :|

Comment: yes, but you can do the hack in the database using left join combined with coalesce. If you want use Addresses to access to the Persons you need the dummy address.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is the reverse of the current mapping, ie.,

```
Class Person
{
    int     Id;
    string  name;
    Address address;
}

Class Address
{
    int     Id;
    string  Address;
}
```

This way you can map the person to his address. In case a single person has multiple addresses you can use a collection of Address.

Also keep singular for your class names like Person instead of Persons since each object refers to a single entity.